# Grouping returned snooze messages in inbox

Tags: gmail

Is there an inbox view that puts snoozed messages that have come back in one segment so they are a lower priority than new messages?

Comment: I think I'm interested in the same thing. Here's my issue:
* I receive a message on (say) 5th Apr 6 pm.
* After that I receive a few more messages.
* On (say) 6th Apr 7 pm, I snooze this message till (say) 7th April 8 am.
* The message is moved from Inbox to the "Snoozed" list.
* On 7th April at 8 am, the message is shown in Inbox at the top, as if it was a "new" message.
* Now even if I open and read the message, this messages is always shown as if it was received on 7th April at 8 am.
* I don't want this. I'd like to see this message listed in Inbox as if it was sent on 5th Apr 6 pm.

Comment: if we want the same thing then please notify me and I'll update your question with my example. If our issues are not the same then I'll create another question with my issue. Please comment. Thank you!